# Running CCleaner with Psexec via Batch File

Tags: windows-7, powershell, ccleaner

Is there a way to setup PSExec within a batch file to silently run CCleaner on remote PC's via a batch file scheduled in Task Scheduler? I understand CCleaner has an /AUTO switch on the command line, but I'm not particularly familiar with PSTools so anyone who may have even done this before (as it seems a pretty nifty idea) could offer some advice!

Cheers.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck trying to use PSExec with CCleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using PowerShell remoting instead of psexec.exe, as this will give you much greater control over the remote session(s). For more information about PowerShell remoting, launch PowerShell and type: `help about_remote`. Alternatively, visit this URL:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847900.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner has Command Line Parameters so should be possible.

https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters

CCleaner.exe /AUTO
CCleaner runs silently and automatically, using the current set of saved options to clean the PC. CCleaner then exits.

CCleaner.exe /AUTO /SHUTDOWN
CCleaner runs silently and automatically, using the current set of saved options to clean the PC. Windows then shuts down automatically..
Note: You cannot run /SHUTDOWN by itself. It must be preceded by /AUTO.